# Calling parent method from within the parent class

Tags: java, methods, nested, parent

Here's an excerpt from my code

```
package dictionary;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class IntelliCwDB extends CwDB {

    public IntelliCwDB(String filename) {
        super(filename);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String word, String clue) {
        System.out.println("inelli");
    }
}
```

And CwDB...

```
package dictionary;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CwDB {
    protected LinkedList<Entry> dict;

    public CwDB(String filename) {
        dict = new LinkedList<Entry>();
        createDB(filename);
    }

    public void add(String word, String clue) {
        System.out.println("cwdb");
        dict.add(new Entry(word, clue));
    }

    protected void createDB(String filename) {
        try {
            BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            while (f.ready()) {
                this.add(f.readLine(), f.readLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `main()` part I create a new `IntelliCwDB` object, which fires the execution of `createDB()`.

The problem is that I want `CwDB.createDB()` to use it's own `CwDB.add()` method, not the one from `IntelliCwDB`.  Is there any other neat solution than creating `CwDB` separately, then passing it into the constructor of `IntelliCwDB` just to rewrite the `LinkedList<Entry>` dict database?

Answer (score 3):

You experienced one of the reasons why **one should not call virtual methods from a constructor**. For more details on this, see [Effective Java 2nd Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 17: *Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it*.

The simplest solution to your problem would be to split the base class method into a nonvirtual (`final` and/or `private`) one, and another, virtual, method, which calls the former in the base class implementation.

@aioobe was faster to provide an example to this :-)

Comment: Most of the nice abstract questions are about who is quickest on the draw :)

Comment: "quickest on the draw",, hahah

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it like this:

- Create a private (or final) version of the `CwDB.add`, lets call it `privateAdd`.
- Let the old `add` method in `CwDB` call this method instead.
- Whenever you want to be sure that the `CwDB`-version of `add` is used, you simply call `privateAdd` instead.

Sample code

```
public class CwDB {

    // ...

    public void add(String word, String clue) {
        privateAdd(word, clue);
    }

    private void privateAdd(String word, String clue) {
        System.out.println("cwdb");
        dict.add(new Entry(word, clue));
    }

    protected void createDB(String filename) {
        // ...
            // "Calling parent method from within the parent class"  :-)
            this.privateAdd(f.readLine(), f.readLine());
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

As @Péter Török correctly points out: You should never call a virtual method (directly or indirectly) from within a constructor. The reason is simple: The sub-class will get to run code before its super class (and itself) is initialized properly. (Whether or not it applies in this particular example stands to reason though.)

Comment: Java is ambiguous in that case, because from what I understand, the switch from CwDB.add() to IntelliCwDB.add() in CwDB constructor is done silently (or to be precise - the switch that has not yet been performed). 
Shouldn't it be better to completely disable such operations? Are they of any real use in normal programming?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure what you mean. The "switch" is never done. All methods are *always* virtual, from the beginning, even in the constructor. What is it you suggest disabling? Method-overriding? In C++ you have the option of making a method non-virtual (as you seem to want in this scenario). Java took another approach, and made all methods virtual, without the option of disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the `add` method to `addInternal` in CwDB, and make a new `add` which calls `addInternal`.  Then in the `createDB` method, call `addInternal` to get the correct method.
Eg.

```
class CwDB {
   ..
   private void addInternal(String word, String clue) {
     ..
   }

   public void add(String word, String clue) {
     addInternal(word, clue);
   }

   public void createDB(String filename) {
      ..
      addInternal(w, c);
      ..
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to mention that he should make the internal add private to make sure it's not overridden.